# Jquery ui slider with turn

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Does anyone know javascript (preferably jquery) script that woud make element draggable with mouse (and preferably keybord when focused) on predefined path with turn? It has to be smooth 180deg turn, so using 3 jquery-ui sliders and switching between them is not an option. Also it has to be javascript solution.

Something like this (red button should be draggable, but its movement should be constrained over gray path)

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1799304/slider.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)